# how to compare two tables having different number of columns in sql

Tags: sql

There are 2 tables - table1 with columns `source` (`varchar`) and table2 with columns `new_source` (`varchar`) and `id` (`number`).

I want to compare table1 with table2. Output should have the `new_source` and `id` which are not present in table2 but present in table1.

Here's an example:

Table1

[image]

Table2

[image]

Output:

[image]

I have tried using not exists and minus but I get only `new_source` but not `id` in the output.

Kindly help me in writing the query.

Comment: Why have you tagged MySQL, SQL Server *and* Oracle SQL Developer..? SQL Server and MySQL are completely different RDBMS and Oracle SQL Developer is an IDE that doesn't work with either of them; it's for Oracle (surprise!) which is another *completely* different RDBMS. Only add tags that are relevant to your question, not random (and conflicting) ones. I have remvoed all the tags bar [tag:sql]. Please retag the RDBMS you are using and only that one, and [edit] your question to show your attempts and explain why they aren't working.

Comment: Your prior questions imply you work with Oracle, which makes your decision to tag [tag:mysql] and [tag:sql-server] and *not* tag [tag:oracle] even more confusing.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from table2
where new_source in
  (select source from table1
   minus
   select new_source from table2);
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post. Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This provided answer could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers. From [Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/27275948).

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . it is not clear where the `id` comes from.  So, I'm thinking:

```
select listagg(source, ',') within group (order by source), 10 as id
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where t2.source = t1.source and t2.source = 10
                 );
```